# Angle between conjugate diameters of an ellipse.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

My book states two seemingly contradicting statements for angle between conjugate diameters of an ellipse.

> Conjugate diameters of the auxiliary circle are perpendicular to each
> other.

My question is, why? Is it an assumption? Or a statement?

> Hence angle between corresponding conjugate diameters of an ellipse
> $\neq 90 ^\circ$

And then it goes ahead and states

> The eccentric angles of the ends of pair of conjugate diameters differ
> by a right angle
> This last statement I have proved also using slopes.

Is there any difference between the angle of the conjugate diameters and the eccentric angle? What do they both represent visually?

Comment: The first statement is about conjugate diameters of a *circle* not an ellipse, and conjugate diameters of a circle are always perpendicular to each other. The second statement is false if the ellipse is a circle, but presumably the author only means that for ellipses in general you cannot depend on conjugate diameters to be perpendicular. Though any ellipse has at least one pair of conjugate diameters that are perpendicular, namely the major and minor axes. I have no idea what "eccentric angles" the author is referring to, so I can't help with that one.

Comment: The eccentric angle is that used in the parametric form of the ellipse equation, and it is related with the corresponding point on the [auxiliary circle](https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/propositions-of-an-ellipse.aspx#auxiliary-circle-of-an-ellipse): as the endpoints of conjugate diameters of an ellipse correspond to perpendicular diameters on the auxiliary circle, the last statement is quite obvious.